# Spring embedded LDAP with LdapTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-ldap

In [spring](/questions/tagged/spring), how embedded [ldap](/questions/tagged/ldap)can be used with [spring-ldap](/questions/tagged/spring-ldap) Template. Currently, my configuration is -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
        <property name="url" value="${PROVIDER_URL}" />
        <property name="base" value="${Search_Base}" />
        <property name="userDn" value="${SECURITY_PRINCIPAL}" />
        <property name="password" value="${SECURITY_CREDENTIALS}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

ContextSource values are available in properties file. Now I want to use embedded ldap -

```xml
<security:ldap-server ldif="classpath:sample.ldif"  root="cn=mojo"/>
```

What would be default port that I will specify in LdapContextSource values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The port of the embedded ldap server defaults to `33389`, see the related [source code](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/ldap/LdapServerBeanDefinitionParser.java#L43).

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was looking for. I will read through the code. Does it requires ApacheDS as dependency?

Answer (score 3):

You can choose a port using the `port` attribute of the `ldap-server` element. See the [namespace appendix](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-ldap-server) in the reference manual. This also gives the default value.

Comment: I didn't know I can specify port no. Thanks.